# Проблема с открытием нужного модального окна в php №2

Tags: javascript, html

повторно столкнулся с проблемой открытия модального окна. На сей раз уже в таблице. То есть при нажатии на ячейку таблицы - должно открывать модальное окно с определенным содержимым.
Примерно пытался осуществить, вот код.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/georgin/eabcp5qv/7/
```

Открывается только последнее окно. Есть еще набросок js вида:

```
$('.js-click-modal').click(function(){
  $(this).closest("td").next('.container_modal').addClass('modal-open');
});

$('.js-close-modal').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.container_modal').removeClass('modal-open');
});
```

Но он не работает вовсе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```js
$('.js-click-modal').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.container_modal').addClass('modal-open');
    });

    $('.js-close-modal').click(function(){
        $('.container_modal').removeClass('modal-open');
    });
```

```css
.features-table
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    color: #2a2a2a;
    background: #fafafa;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.features-table td
{
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

.features-table td span
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 250px;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.features-table tbody td
{
    width: 150px;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 7px;
}


.features-table td.grey,
.features-table th.grey
{
    background: #efefef;
    background: rgba(144,144,144,0.15);
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.container_modal > .btn1 {
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.modal1 {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    top: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 9;
    color: #000;
}
.modal1 .header {
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font: 300 24px Lato;
    position: relative;
}
.modal1 .body {
    padding: 20px 0;
    font: 300 16px Lato;
}

.btn1 {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #65b5e3, #4e4db6);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 4%;
    top: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn1:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container_modal.modal-open .modal1 {
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="features-table table-marks marks">
            <colgroup>
                <col>
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td><span>Критерий</span></td>
                <td><span>Критерий</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a class="js-click-modal black">1</a>
                  <div class="container_modal">
                     <div class="modal1">
                        <div class="header"><p>1</p></div>
                        <div class="body">
                           <a class="btn1 js-close-modal">Close</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>                       
                </td>                   
                <td><a class="js-click-modal black">2</a>
                  <div class="container_modal">
                     <div class="modal1">
                        <div class="header"><p>2</p></div>
                        <div class="body">
                           <a class="btn1 js-close-modal">Close</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>                       
                </td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a class="js-click-modal black">4</a>
                  <div class="container_modal">
                     <div class="modal1">
                        <div class="header"><p>4</p></div>
                        <div class="body">
                           <a class="btn1 js-close-modal">Close</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>                       
                </td>                   
                <td><a class="js-click-modal black">5</a>
                  <div class="container_modal">
                     <div class="modal1">
                        <div class="header"><p>5</p></div>
                        <div class="body">
                           <a class="btn1 js-close-modal">Close</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>                       
                </td>      
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает)